# Yii2 Gridview CheckboxColumn, background color of the check box cell

Tags: yii2

Is there any way to set a background color only for the checkbox column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for styling column properties you can use options

```
......
'columns' => [
    // ...
    [
     'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
     / you may configure additional properties here
     'options' => ['class'=> 'your_check_box_class' , style =>'background-color: #ff0000;'],
    ],
],
```

for checkbox content you can use contentOptions

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html